# List.Count resets to zero

Tags: c#

I want to create a list with 11 entries, but `List.Count` resets to zero after this code.

There are no entries added to the list. What is wrong?

```
List<Animation> animations = new List<Animation>();

animations[0] = new Animation(new List<Rectangle>(10), 
                                     Content.Load<Texture2D>("pictures"), 
                                     TimeSpan.FromSeconds(2), 
                                     Animation.Animationsablaeufe.vorrück);
```

Comment: Use add method: `animations.Add(new Animation(...))`

Comment: How are you invoking List.Count? Can you show the calling code?

Comment: This code show throw an exception, not just have zero `Count`.

Comment: this isn't an array you have to use -Add- method

Answer (score 2):

```
List<Animation> animations = new List<Animation>(); // count should be 0

animations.Add(new Animation(...)); // count should be 1
animations.Add(new Animation(...)); // count should be 2

// etc...
```

You can also use the following notation, which is equivalent:

```
List<Animation> animations = new List<Animation>
{
   new Animation(...),
   new Animation(...),
   new Animation(...),
   new Animation(...),
   ...
   new Animation(...)
};
```

Answer (score 0):

```
List<Animation> Animations = new List<Animation>();

Animations.Add(new Animation);

Animations.Count();
```

Comment: Don't call `Count()` on a List. So wasteful.

Comment: @HenkHolterman why is it wasteful? As far as I know, the LINQ `Count()` method will use the `Count` property on a `List<T>`, which is **O(1)**.

Comment: @Sahuagin `Count()` is an extension on `IEnumerable<>`, I'm not so sure it is smart enough to return the property.

Comment: @HenkHolterman from the msdn page: ***If the type of source implements ICollection<T>, that implementation is used to obtain the count of elements. Otherwise, this method determines the count.***